# SQLAlchemy: Why does appending to this many-to-one relationship fail?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two classes, a `Parent` and `Child`. A parent can have multiple children. In my program, I append children to parents as needed. This consistently succeeds for the first child but fails for the second. Here are my relationships

```
class Parent(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship(
        'Child',
        backref=db.backref('parent', order_by=id)
    )

class Child(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_fk = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('parent.id')
    )
```

And then the code to add one child at a time:

```
print(parent.children)
parent.children.append(Child())
print(parent.children)
database.update_object(parent)  # Uses a scoped session to merge and commit.
```

Here is my update code:

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    try:
        yield db.session
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Rolling back database')
        print(e)
        db.session.rollback()

def update_object(obj):
    with session_scope() as session:
        session.merge(obj)
```

When I log the results from the program, I get this:

Adding first child:

```
[]
[<Child None>]
```

Adding second child:

```
[<Child 219L>]
[<Child 219L>, <Child None>]
Rolling back database
(OperationalError) (1048, "Column 'parent_fk' cannot be null") 'UPDATE child SET parent_fk=%s WHERE child.id = %s' (None, 218L)
```

What am I missing?

FWIW, a consistent pattern is that the second `Child` instance has an `id` that is 1 lower than the first.

Comment: Can you post the complete model classes?

Comment: @univerio, I've added them to the post.

Comment: The code for `database.update_object` may be relevant.

Comment: @gwg One way to solve this issue would be to avoid the `append`. You could simply create two new `Child` instances: `ch1 = Child(parent_fk=parent.id); ch2 = Child(parent_fk=parent.id); session.add(ch1); session.add(ch2); session.commit()`. This wouldn't explain the error you're receiving, but it might get you up-and-running in the meanwhile by explicitly adding the children, with the foreign-key explicitly mapped.

Comment: @gwg What happens when, after you append the second `Child`, you `print parent.children[1].parent_fk` ?

Comment: When I print parent.children[-1].parent_fk, I get `None`. But if I print `parent.id`, I get the correct ID. Really weird.

Comment: @this-vidor, maybe you're right. I got that context manager from [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html). My understanding is that Flask-SQLAlchemy manages the sessions for me, essentially binding a session to a single HTTP request/response cycle. I use the context manager just to encapsulate the `try/catch` and `commit/rollback` logic. Ultimately, I'm just `yield`-ing the session provided by Flask-SQLAlchemy... Just tested, and I get the same error if I just try `db.session.merge` without the context manager.

Comment: @gwg I see. For one thing, you don't need the merge statement. You can simply `append`, then `commit`. It looks to me like the exception is being thrown by the merge, not the commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to usage of `session.merge`. Instead if you use `session.add`, it should work properly, as `session.add` performs a `insert-or-update` operation, which I believe is what you intend here.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849567/can-sqlalchemys-session-merge-update-its-result-with-newer-data-from-the-data) illustrates the use of `session.merge`, and I found it very useful. Linking to it, rather than attempt to explain the same using poorer language.

*edit with code example showing problem is resolved when using `add` instead of `merge`.*

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('postgresql://hal:hal@localhost/hal')

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('Child', backref=backref('parent', order_by=id))

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_fk = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_maker = sessionmaker(engine)
s = scoped_session(session)

parent = Parent()
parent.children.append(Child())

s.add(parent)
s.commit()
engine.execute('select * from child').fetchall()
# prints: [(1, 1)]

parent2 = Parent()
s.add(parent2)
s.commit()

parent2.children.append(Child())
parent2.children.append(Child())
parent2.children.append(Child())

# ``parent2`` does not need to be ``added`` to the session again, as 
# user A. Vidor pointed out in the comments. 
# Committing the session will persist the changes, i.e. adding the 
# related three child rows to the database.
s.commit()

engine.execute('select * from child').fetchall()
# prints: [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2)]
```

If I understand correctly, that is the desired behavior, achieved with `session.add`

Comment: I should have made this clear, but the parent instance does exist. I'm actually pulling all the parents out of the database, iterating over them, and adding two children to each. My understanding was that I called `merge` on the parent because it was already created. Could SQLAlchemy have lost track of the parent somehow, because you're right that it seems to fail at `parent_fk`.

Comment: I don't think merge is what you need here, even if the parent object already exists in the database. see edited answer with code example.

Comment: @HaleemurAli I agree that `merge` is not needed. I believe the second `s.add(parent2)` is also not needed. Once `parent2` has already been added and mapped, all that is required is to append the `Child()` objects, then `commit`! SQLAlchemy is very clever that way.

Comment: yup, you're right. the 2nd add is unnecessary, didn't think about it while typing this up because it has no visible effect. removing the offending line.

Comment: @HaleemurAli, the real answer is that my code was executing in a separate thread with its own `session` instance. When I tried `add`, I got `InvalidRequestError: Object '' is already attached to session`, which clued me into the problem: my `database.update_object` uses the application's globally accessible session manager, but this one process uses a thread-local session. Once I called `my_threads_session.merge`, the code worked fine.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because you have a nice explanation of the difference between `add` and `merge`, and because I did not give enough detail for you to answer correctly.

Comment: @gwg, thanks for the update. happy you figured it out.